# "Error: This action with HTTP GET is not supported by NextAuth.js"

Tags: post, get, credentials, next.js13, next-auth

My current project involves the use of credentials signin using next-auth.
In my registration form, i have this code that does an API call to the signup function.

[projects\components\RegisterForm.jsx]:

```
 async function onSubmit(values){
        console.log(values)
        const options = {
            method: "POST",
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(values)
        }
        await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup', options)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                if(data) router.push('http://localhost:3000/login')
            }).catch(error => {
                // Handle server-side errors here
                console.error('Fetch error:', error);
            });
    }
```

In my signup function, i typed in what I think is pretty straightforward,

[projects\pages\api\auth\signup.js]:

```
import { connectToDB } from '@/database/connect_to_mongodb';
import User from '@/models/user';
import { hash } from 'bcryptjs';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    await connectToDB();

    // Only POST method is accepted
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
      if (!req.body) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "Don't have form data...!" });
      }
      const { name, email, password } = req.body;

      // Check for duplicate users
      const checkExisting = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (checkExisting) {
        return res.status(422).json({ message: "User Already Exists...!" });
      }

      // Hash password and create user
      const hashedPassword = await hash(password, 12);
      const newUser = new User({ name, email, password: hashedPassword });
      await newUser.save();

      res.status(201).json({ status: true, user: newUser });
    } else {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "HTTP method not valid. Only POST is accepted." });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred." });
  }
}
```

and the credentials provider code is inside [...nextauth].js file.

[projects\pages\api\auth[…nextauth].js]:

```
export default NextAuth({
    providers : [
        // Google Provider
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
        }),
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                connectToDB().catch(error => { error: "Connection Failed...!" });
        
                // Check user existence
                const user = await User.findOne({ email: credentials.email });
                if (!user) {
                    throw new Error("No user found with this email. Please sign up...!");
                }
        
                // Compare passwords
                const passwordMatch = await compare(credentials.password, user.password);
        
                // Incorrect password
                if (!passwordMatch || user.email !== credentials.email) {
                    throw new Error("Username or password doesn't match");
                }
        
                // Return user information including name
                return { email: user.email, name: user.name };
            }
        })
    ],
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    session: {
        // strategy: 'jwt',
        jwt: true,
    }
})
```

I was able to make "POST" requests to the signup function. However, once my team mates try, they couldn't even fetch "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup". Instead they get "Error: This action with HTTP GET is not supported by NextAuth.js". Anyone could explain what's happening here or have come across the same problems?

Tried looking at firewall settings on my teammate's pc but that's not it.

Comment: Managed to fix this issue. For unknown reasons, vscode or rather, Nextjs saved my signup Api path as "signUp" instead of "signup". I remember changing the name some time ago. Didnt realise that it would cause these errors.